# Why does image from zip file not display in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import Salesforce_Images from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/trailhead_logo';
export default class ImageDisplay extends LightningElement {
  
  salesforceImageUrl = Salesforce_Images;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Use Static Resource in Lightning Web Component">
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal_small">

            <img src={salesforceImageUrl}>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

I have stored image in static  resource with name trailhead logo. but image is not appearing.

I have stored image in a zip file, then uploaded to static resource but not succeded.

Answer (score 1):

if your image is in a zip file you should do it like this:

```javascript
salesforceImageUrl = Salesforce_Images + '/images/yourImageName.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

for the code you have, try creating a static resource like this
Static Resource-> New-> name it 'trailhead_logo' -> Choose file -> Upload the image (not zip file) -> make cache public -> Save

in case if you want to use a zip file as static resource, please share the zip file path for further clarification, as the reference path may vary